# "Cannot be resolved to a type" Error while compiling a Java project in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse

One day I opened eclipse and randomly got this "(x) Cannot be resolved to a type" (x could be, for example "String"). This happens on all my existing projects, and all projects I create. I cleaned all projects, restarted eclipse, and restarted my computer, all to no avail. What could be the cause and how can i fix it? Please provide an explanation as to what the cause is. Thank you.

Comment: Restart eclipse with `eclipse -clean`.

Comment: If this is a large project, then check the lower right-hand corner.  If it's still saying that it's building the workspace or something, you'll need to wait for it to finish.  In my experience, Eclipse often marks symbols as "cannot be resolved" or the like even before it's finished gathering all the information it needs from other places; as it puts all the information together, the errors eventually go away.

Comment: Did you randomly upgrade your installed Java version, making references to the old one (on the Installed JREs preference page and in your projects) invalid?

Comment: sometimes close and open project in eclipse will fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you change Java version from the build path.
You could try this. 
Check Java version, change it if it's not what it's supposed to be.
restart eclipse. 
All errors should automatically go.